# Не работает flex-direction: row

Tags: html, css, frontend, scss

Прошу не судить строго, я начинающий в веб разработке. На CSS + HTML все получалось. Осваиваю препроцессоры и столкнулась с такой проблемой - не срабатывает display: flex; (блоки не выстраиваются в ряд). Классы скопированы из HTML с помощью плагина csstractor. Ставлю принудительно flex-direction:row, но what__body так и остается под what__image.

index.html

```
           <div class="what">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="what__row">
                        <div class="what__image">
                            <img src="img/image_2.jpg" alt="">
                        <div class="what__body">
                            <div class="what__title title"></div>
                            <div class="what__text">
                                <p></p>
                                <p></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

style.scss

```
 .what {
    padding: 50px 0;
    &__row {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction:row;
    }
    &__image {
        flex: 0 0 430px;
    }
    &__body {
        flex: 1 1 auto;
        padding: 0 0 0 30px;
    }
    &__title {
    margin: 0 0 33px 0;
}
    &__text {
        & p{
            margin: 0 0 25px 0;
            color: #333333;
            font-size: 16px;
            line-height: 24px;
        }
    }
}
.container {
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы не в том месте закрыли what__image, закройте его перед what__body :

```
         <div class="what">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="what__row">
                    <div class="what__image">
                        <img src="img/image_2.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="what__body">
                        <div class="what__title title"></div>
                        <div class="what__text">
                            <p></p>
                            <p></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Вы забыли закрывающий тег `what__image`

```css
.what {
  padding: 50px 0;
  &__row {
    display: flex;
  }
  &__image {
    flex: 0 0 430px;
  }
  &__body {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    padding: 0 0 0 30px;
  }
  &__title {
    margin: 0 0 33px 0;
  }
  &__text {
    & p {
      margin: 0 0 25px 0;
      color: #333333;
      font-size: 16px;
      line-height: 24px;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="what">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="what__row">
      <div class="what__image">
        <img src="img/image_2.jpg" alt="pic">
        <p>test</p>
      </div>
      <div class="what__body">
        <div class="what__title title"></div>
        <div class="what__text">
          <p>test</p>
          <p>test</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```